# How to SELECT rows on a table with COUNT from other table in a range of time?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables:

```
users
-----
id                  INT
name                VARCHAR(20)
email               VARCHAR(40)

user_fans
----------
id                  INT
user_id             INT  /* linked to users.id */
fan_id              INT  /* linked to users.id */
time_created        INT  /* unix timestamp */
```

I can get all rows from table `users` with additional field named `num_fans` using the following query

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.email, COUNT(f.id) AS num_fans
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_fans f ON u.id=f.user_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.name, u.email
ORDER BY num_fans DESC
```

The problem is I need to get the `num_fans` in a range of time. I tried this query

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.email, COUNT(f.id) AS num_fans
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_fans f ON u.id=f.user_id
WHERE f.time_created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-5-1 00:00:00')
GROUP BY u.id, u.name, u.email
ORDER BY num_fans DESC
```

But the query above will return only users which already have fans. I want the rest of users also returned with num_fans=0.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the condition to the `on`:

```
SELECT u.id, 
       u.name, 
       u.email, 
       COUNT(f.id) AS num_fans 
FROM users u LEFT JOIN user_fans f 
             ON u.id=f.user_id 
             and f.time_created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-5-1 00:00:00') 
GROUP BY u.id, u.name, u.email ORDER BY num_fans DESC
```

***Update***
(Added an explanation on @Gardon Dave's suggestion)

The difference between what you have and this is:

In your query you have the condition in the `WHERE` clause. This is applied after the Join,(see this as filtering on top of the join). If a row does not follow this condition it will be eliminated. Outer joined rows that do not have an entry in the `user_fans` table will not satisfy this condition (value will be NULL).

Having the condition in the `on` will join the users table only to the subset of the `user_fans` table - the outer join happens after this filtering.

Comment: It is worth explaining why.  When the condition is in the "where" clause, the left join produces NULL and the condition always fails.  When the condition is in the "on" clause, it is included in the join criteria.  My preference, though, is to include the condition as a subquery, so it is very clear how it should be applied.

Comment: I want to vote up your answer, but it looks like I need more rep for doing that. Thanks for both of you.

Comment: I dont think you need more rep for viting up the answer. You would have tried to vote it up after accepting it. Anyway, glad I was of help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding is null to the condition:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.email, COUNT(f.id) AS num_fans  
FROM users u  
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_fans f ON u.id=f.user_id  
WHERE f.time_created is null or f.time_created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-5-1 00:00:00')  
GROUP BY u.id, u.name, u.email  
ORDER BY num_fans DESC
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` (which OP is using) and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` are one and the same. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html. And having the condition in the `ON` part will be cleaner (and more efficient I think)

Comment: @nivas I edited the description of the solution. One difference will be that my solution will also show user_fans rows with time_created=null where yours probably won't although I don't have mysql installed to test it.